# Sitecore smart publish failing with remote script block using powershell

Tags: powershell

Invoking RemoteScript block and publishing item on remote server through octopus but getting error.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Import-Module -Name SPE
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $OctopusParameters["HttpAuth.Password"] -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($OctopusParameters["HttpAuth.Username"], $secpasswd)
Write-Host "Creating Remote Session"
$session = New-ScriptSession -Username $OctopusParameters["Sitecore.ThemeUploadUser"] -Password $OctopusParameters["Sitecore.ThemeUploadPassword"] -ConnectionUri $SiteUrl -Credential $credential
if ($session -ne $null) {
    write-host "Connected to Sitecore server $sitecoreUrl"
} else {
    write-error "Login failed to Sitecore server $sitecoreUrl for user $(pubUserName)."
}
Write-Host "Invoking Smart Publish Job"

# Smart Publish Site
$jobId = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
        (Publish-Item -Path "master:\" -PublishMode Smart -Recurse -AsJob).Handle.ToString()
}
Write-Host "Waiting for job to finish"
Wait-RemoteSitecoreJob -Session $session -Id $jobId -Delay 30 -Verbose
Write-Host "Job Completed"
Stop-ScriptSession -Session $session
```

Output getting :

Creating Remote Session

Connected to Sitecore server

Invoking Smart Publish Job

Invoke-RemoteScript : Server response: Not Found

- $jobId = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {

For debugging purpose i checked connection with sitecore and as in the above output it is connecting to sitecore.

I doubt if I am missing any setting on sitecore side. I am working with Sitecore 9.0

Update:

I tried to debug the Invoke-RemoteScript and below is the response:

[image]